# Creating the Sesame repository

Tags: java, tomcat, rdf, sesame

I am quite new to Java Sesame. I have read through the [documentation provided for Sesame](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view). Unfortunately lots of things were not very clear to me. I started with creating the repository as in the code below:

```
import org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException;
import org.openrdf.repository.manager.RemoteRepositoryManager;
import org.openrdf.repository.sail.SailRepository;
public class RDF{

public void create() throws RepositoryException
{
    File dataDir = new File("myFile");
    Repository repo = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore(dataDir));
    repo.initialize();
    String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/rep";
    RemoteRepositoryManager manager = new RemoteRepositoryManager(serverUrl);
    manager.initialize();
    }
}
```

I am using `Tomcat 6`. I run the code in `Eclipse`. I right click the Dynamic Project and select `Run on server`. The codes were taken from the documentation itself. My questions are what is creating the file `dataDir` for?

Is this address `http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/rep` of the location where the repository is created? After starting Tomcat, I use the above link but it shows me there is an error.

How can I make sure that the repository has successfully been created and how can I start to use it. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up two things:

- creating a local repository (a MemoryStore persisted to dataDir), and
- a remote repository living on the Sesame server

If you just want to create a persistent repository the first option is sufficient. If you want to also have a full Sesame server with all its UI and services then you have to install it, set it up first and use the second option.

In both cases, you can use the `RepositoryManager` API. [An introduction to RepositoryManager](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/the-repositorymanager/).

You wouldn't typically start the Sesame server and workbench via Eclipse. You would use a [standalone installation as described in the documentation](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#chapter-server-install).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually I used the openrdf_workbench by deploying the two war files for Sesame in Tomcat. I have created a new repository but did not know how to connect to that repository I have created. I have some RDF statements in Java and would like to add them into the repository created in openrdf-workbench. May you please guide me at this point how to connect and these statements into the repository. Thank you

Comment: No problem. You can upload the RDF file from the workbench UI. Just select (or create and select) the right repository and then find the upload button.. Or do you want do do it programatically?

Comment: I think I should do it programatically because I have created the RDF statements as subject, predicate and object by following the same tutorial. I have a huge amount of data. What do you think?

Comment: In my opinion, if you just need the data there to play with it, you can upload it via workbench, it's easier. On the other hand, programmatically it's also not so difficult: http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#section-repository-api1

Comment: The relevant JavaDoc: http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/repository/RepositoryConnection.html#add(java.io.File, java.lang.String, org.openrdf.rio.RDFFormat, org.openrdf.model.Resource...)

Comment: One more question, please. What does this RDF contain? I have created a json file that contains the RDF statements in Java. The other question is: Do you think I can create a repository using openrdf-workbench and then access this repository programmatically? Your guide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly create a repository in workbench and then access it via the API: Repository repository = repositoryManager.getRepository("RepositoryID"); Read the introduction to RepositoryManager for more details. I don't understand your first question. Are you asking what is RDF? Or do you want to know what your example file contains? (I have no way of knowing the without you showing me the file).

Comment: Thank you for answering the second question. Regarding the first question, You told me earlier that you can upload the RDF file when you create a repository in openrdf-workbench. what is the extension of this file? I have a json file which has the RDF statements I created. Does the RDF file have a particular format? What is that RDF file that I need to upload?

Comment: If you go to the upload feature in workbench you'll see the formats (in a drop-down menu) it recognizes. So your file has to be in one of those formats - the extension of the file doesn't matter IMO. JSON with Java RDF sounds strange..maybe post an example but I highly doubt it's one of the standard formats, you'll probably have to convert it first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. You have clarified some points for me. Hope I can get started. I am afraid I will ask you some questions on the way and hope this will not bother you.